# number of executions of script

Tags: grep, scripting, ps

I am trying to find number of runs of a script but its always 2 even though only one running.

```
sh 11.sh
1
 11.sh already running,exiting..
```

here is code.

```
ps -ef | grep -v grep | grep -c "$0"
if [[ `ps -ef | grep -v grep | grep -c "$0"` -gt "1" ]]; then
            `echo " $0 already running,exiting.."`
fi
```

Comment: Consider using `pgrep` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Considering only a single instance of *11.sh* running, and given this *11.sh*:

```
n=`ps -ef | grep -wc "$0"` n=$((n-2))
echo $n
[ $n -gt "1" ] &&  echo " $0 already running,exiting.."
```

Running `sh 11.sh` outputs:

```
 1
```

---

The backticks and the `grep` add two more `ps` lines.  Since we know the number is *2*, just subtract `n-2` to get the correct number.

Comment: This code can give false positives. For example, `grep` will match `211.sh` or `murphy11.sh` or `11.shar`

Comment: @fpmurphy1, Thanks.  Added a `-w` to `grep`.

Answer (score 1):

Using pgrep  ...

```
#!/bin/bash

PNAME=$(basename "$0")

COUNT=$(pgrep -c -x  $PNAME)

(( COUNT > 1 ))  &&  echo "$0 already running, exiting..."
```